# Submit only certain fields

Tags: java, forms, jsf, submit, partial

I have a huge form and I would like to submit only the fields that were modified on client side. So I need to decide, in client side, what fields to submit. Is it possible?

Submit always all fields and handle that in server side is not an option.

Comment: JSF 1.x or 2.x? Why exactly is submitting the entire form a problem? Why exactly is handling all fields not an option? (JSF does that automagically, so the problem is now less understandable). Is it an autogenerated table with a million of fields or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `disable` the fields that were not modified. Inputs with the `disabled` attribute are  not submitted.

- HTML4: [17.12.1 Disabled controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled)
- HTML5: [4.10.19.2 Enabling and disabling form controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/attributes-common-to-form-controls.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls)